# Programmatically query latest kernel version to rebuild driver?

Tags: kernel

Is there a way to programmatically query the latest kernel version for Ubuntu 20.04 - e.g. 5.4.0-88, 5.4.0-91, 5.4.0-92, etc. perhaps querying a URL of sorts?

I need to build an automated process that rebuilds a driver to a particular kernel version. Usually, DKMS would take care of this, but the driver is for a server with security restrictions and cannot have build tools installed on it. It is also not able to contact servers on the internet, patches are applied from a local server.

The build process would query for the latest 5.4.0-x kernel and if there is a new one for which headers haven't been installed yet, install the appropriate headers package, then rebuild the driver against those headers.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a rather crude solution I came up with.  It essentially gets the `linux-image-generic` package information for `focal-updates` by reading the Packages file for the apt repository.  The package version is then extracted, and the version in the dependency name if that is the format you need.

`curl -s http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz | zcat | sed -n -e '/^Package: linux-image-generic$/,/^$/p' | sed -n -e '/^Depends:/s/^.*linux-image-\([-.0-9]*\)-.*/\1/p' -e '/^Version:/s/^Version: //p'`

Here is the command in action

```
$ curl -s http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz | zcat | sed -n -e '/^Package: linux-image-generic$/,/^$/p' | sed -n -e '/^Depends:/s/^.*linux-image-\([-.0-9]*\)-.*/\1/p' -e '/^Version:/s/^Version: //p'
5.4.0.92.96
5.4.0-92
```